# How to show all TextField in a view that stored in a array / Swift 5

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

I have a tapGesture, that every time when you click on it a new TextField displays and will saved in a array.
I can create multiple TextField and can store them in a Array, but I have no idea, how I can display them on a view.
At the Moment only the first one will be shown in the view.
I want to build something similar like snapchat with the text.

```
var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 300.0, height:30.0))


func addTapGestureToTextImageView() {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTextImage))
    textImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

@objc func handleTextImage() {

    textFields.append(myTextField)
    let myTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 300.0, height:30.0))
    for i in 0..<textFields.count {
        myTextField.tag = i
        view.addSubview(textFields[i])
        print(textFields[i])
    }
    print(textFields.count)
}
```

Comment: What is . happening is that you stack all the textFields on top of eachother as you give them the same frame and x + y position. What you want to do is update the x and y position.

Comment: and how can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pile them vertically you have to increment the y with the height for each textField and hence change it's frame.

```
for i in 0..<textFields.count {
            var field = textFields[i]
            field.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30*i, width: 300, height: 30)
            view.addSubview(field)
            print(textFields[i])
        }
```

It will look something like this. But you will need to tweak it to properly align it.

My suggestion would be to put a `UIStackView` in the baseView and then use it's `addArrangedSubview()` and it will do the stacking for you.

Comment: to be vertical you need to manipulate the y axis not x-axis .  CGRect(x: 30, y: 40 * i, width: 300, height: 30)

Answer (score 0):

Use `stackView` for this:

```
lazy var textFieldsView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.spacing = 4
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.frame.size.width = 300
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    return stackView
}()


@objc func handleTextImage() {

    let myTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300.0, height: 30.0))
    for pair in textFields.enumerated() {
        pair.element.tag = pair.offset
        textFieldsView.addArrangedSubview(pair.element)
    }

    // Update stackView frame if needed
}
```

Comment: With this he will add a new stackView each time he presses the button. The `stackView` should be added once, and outside the `selector`

Comment: I declared the stack view outside of the selector. but the textviews are not shown

Comment: Becareful, Don't `addSubView` instead of `addArrangedSubview` for `StackView`.

Comment: hmm nothing happens, I also get a error at view.addSubview(textFieldsView) : Variable used within its own initial value

Comment: Sry, I have no access to IDE, answer edited. Use `stackView`